# CSS3 Multiple color filled div

Tags: css

How can i fill a div with multiple colors using css3. Just like the following Image.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why not using a border?

Comment: It's really unclear what your use-case is here. There are a lot of ways to achieve something that looks like the image you've posted, but the correct answer may depend on what you're planning to use it for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this using css gradients.

something like this:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, orange, orange 20%, black 20%, black);
```

I updated the answer from the duplicated answer in the comments ([Can I apply multiple background colors with CSS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457406/can-i-apply-multiple-background-colors-with-css3)):

http://jsfiddle.net/UES6U/252/

Answer (score -1):

Within the div tag that you want two colours in, create two more divs. e.g.:

```
<div>
<div style="background:black"></div>
<div style="background:orange"></div>
</div>
```