# Trying to put a background image on top of a color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to put an image on top of a color background. In the beginning, I thought this is valid:

```
background: white, url(example.png);
```

However, according to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#backgrounds), this isn't valid. I must enter a `<bg-image>`, so I must either create a 1x1 image with the color I want, or [use a gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457406/can-i-apply-multiple-background-colors-with-css3) with the same color on two ends.

```
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(255,255,255) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%), url(example.png);
```

I did not expect it to not accept `white` as a valid value. This definitely surprised me.

Is there any way to achieve the same effect without creating a useless gradient?

---

If I set `background-color` to `white`, the result will be something like this:

[image]

Bonus code:

```
padding: 2,
backgroundColor: "white",
backgroundImage: "url(url.png)",
backgroundPosition: "-168px -144px",
backgroundClip: "content-box",
backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
//I'm setting all these with JavaScript
```

Any answer that can achieve the effect I'm trying to do is okay.

Comment: Remove the comma - `,`? http://jsfiddle.net/2D8R6/

Comment: @JoshC - Actually the situation I'm having is a bit different than normal cases. I have a `div` with padding with `content-box` so that I can just apply the top and left offset to select the part I want from a sprite sheet. But since I'm doing it with `content-box`, if I specify the `background-color` there will be a gap between the image and the border. That's why I'm trying to apply it as a background so that I can make it to fill up the whole box.

Answer (score 2):

Your have to mix both the long-hand notation and the short-hand notation. Also, you need to set multiple properties for background-clip

```
div {
    background: url(https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yl/r/djWWR4XJTnA.png), white;
    background-position: -168px -144px;
    background-clip: content-box, border-box;
    background-origin: border-box;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kf8Ku/1/)

This way, your image is clipped at content box, and the white background at the border box. Also, the solid color *must* be the last.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use the shorthand notation for background, and the spec is listing the longhand notations.

http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/

Remove the comma from the code you pasted, and it'll work.

Comment: Any way you can post your actual code to codepen/jsfiddle/github/somewhere?

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Kf8Ku/ You can see that there's a gap between the white background and the border.

Comment: Take a look at vals answer below. Looks like that's what you needed, right?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the order, the background is readed at least in chrome like this:

```
  background: url('/example'), white
   background-image: url('/example')
   ...
   background-color: white
```