# How to create multiple background color in my case?

Tags: html, css

i am trying to create a multiple solid background color in my div.

I have found this post. [Can I apply multiple background colors with CSS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457406/can-i-apply-multiple-background-colors-with-css3)

but not sure what it means.

I have this

```
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, grey 20%, red 30%, yellow 10%, blue 100%)
```

The boundary between red and yellow is solid but grey/red boundary and blue/yellow boundary are blurry. How do I make them all solid?

Thanks

Comment: YOU CANT, Thats what a gradient is!! use multiple divs or a divwidth x 1px high image of the colours you want and repeat it down the page.

Comment: That's false. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47ecE/)

```
#test {
    /* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #6E6E6E 25%, #F20000 25%, #F20000 50%, #FFFF21 50%, #FFFF21 75%, #1231FF 75%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #6E6E6E 25%, #F20000 25%, #F20000 50%, #FFFF21 50%, #FFFF21 75%, #1231FF 75%);

/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #6E6E6E 25%, #F20000 25%, #F20000 50%, #FFFF21 50%, #FFFF21 75%, #1231FF 75%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(.25, #6E6E6E), color-stop(.25, #F20000), color-stop(.5, #F20000), color-stop(.5, #FFFF21), color-stop(.75, #FFFF21), color-stop(.75, #1231FF));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #6E6E6E 25%, #F20000 25%, #F20000 50%, #FFFF21 50%, #FFFF21 75%, #1231FF 75%);

/* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #6E6E6E 25%, #F20000 25%, #F20000 50%, #FFFF21 50%, #FFFF21 75%, #1231FF 75%);
}
```

Created here: http://ie.microsoft.com/TEStdrive/Graphics/CSSGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html

Answer (score 0):

You can; the trick is to repeat the ending position of the previous color as the starting position for your new color. Like so:

```
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, grey 20%, red 20%, red 30%, yellow 30%, yellow 80%, blue 80%, blue 100%)
```

Basically this defines grey as being from 0-20%, red from 20%-30%, yellow 30%-80% and blue 80%-100%.