# Different color background in same div

Tags: html, css

I feel like this should be much easier than I am making it...I'm looking for a solution to have 1 solid color extend from the left and end at a logo, then have a second solid color extend all the way to the right. I want the wrapper divs to extend 100%. So something like:

```
<div id="header-wrap"><!--100% page width-->
  <div id="header"><!--1000px centered fixed width-->
    <div id="logo"></div><!-- align left-->
    <div id="nav"></div><!-- align right-->
  </div>
  <div id="sub-header-wrap">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's an image showing what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried some CSS already? On what basis can we start working?

Comment: Create fiddle please, Also explain more what do you want?

Comment: fiddle will be helpful to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot that goes into this.

Let me start of with a link to a working fiddle: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4r6JS/1/embedded/result/)**

---

How can I explain this?

Basically I have the two full-width divs that have the full background color. Inside those two divs I have a div classified as `.inner` that has 80% of the width (which can be whatever you want) that is aligned to the center with margins.

Inside `.inner` I have a left div and a right div of the proper sizes to contain the logo/navigation. Inside the left divs, I have another div, `.shade` that will darken the left side of the header.

The `.left` divs are relatively positioned and the `.shade` divs are absolutely positioned.

### CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}

header
{
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
}

header .top
{
    background: #00a;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

header .inner
{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;
    text-align: left;
}

header .inner .logo, header .inner .left
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0;

    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;

    padding: 10px 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

header .inner .right
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 78%;
    margin: 0;

    text-align: right;
}

header li
{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}

header .bottom
{
    background: #ca0;
}

header .shade
{
    width: 1000%;
    height: 100%;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;

    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="top" align="center">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="logo">
                Logo
                <div class="shade"></div>
            </div>     
            <div class="right">
                <li>Nav 1</li>
                <li>Nav 2</li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="left">
                Subtext
                <div class="shade"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <li>Link</li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

### [Full JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4r6JS/1/)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, try something like this in a separate [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/DEFAULT.asp) file, or within a `<style>` block. It's not tested though, sorry.

```
#header {
  margin: 0 auto; /* for centering */
  width: 1000px;
}
#logo {
  float: left;
  width: 250px; /* for example */
  background-color: red; /* for example */
}
#nav {
  float: right;
  width: 750px; /* for example */
  background-color: blue; /* for example */
}
```

UPDATE:

If you can afford CSS3, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457406/can-i-apply-multiple-background-colors-with-css3) can be intresting for you as well.

Comment: Thanks for the example. This would be fine but I'm looking to extend those 2 colors (red to the left, blue to the right) out into a wrapper div that extends to 100% of the screen