# How can I put multicolor in background?

Tags: css

[image]

Please tell me how can I set multicolor on background screen as shown in image that I have attached...

Comment: [search: css gradient](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=css+gradient&oq=css+gradient&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i60l3j0l2.1415j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I'm afraid you could even have googled the term ["CSS multi color background"](https://www.google.co.il/#q=css+multi+color+background) :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I apply multiple background colors with CSS3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457406/can-i-apply-multiple-background-colors-with-css3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Css gradient

A nice explanation is given here
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

linear gradient example

```
#grad {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red , blue); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, red, blue); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, red, blue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red , blue); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a background gradient.

You can generate a CSS background gradient using the colorzilla tool here:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

[**-- See Demo --**](http://jsfiddle.net/74vcaz7c/)

```
background: #72c4e8; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #72c4e8 0%, #2260dd 50%, #72c4e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#72c4e8), color-stop(50%,#2260dd), color-stop(100%,#72c4e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #72c4e8 0%,#2260dd 50%,#72c4e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #72c4e8 0%,#2260dd 50%,#72c4e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #72c4e8 0%,#2260dd 50%,#72c4e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #72c4e8 0%,#2260dd 50%,#72c4e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#72c4e8', endColorstr='#72c4e8',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
```