# Multiple vertical background colors in CSS3

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-color

**Problem:**

Trying to create a solution that would allow me to have five multiple background colors that fill out a webpage regardless of width. I have managed to do this with 5 div tags but I wonder if it's possible to do this completely using CSS3?

**The outcome I would like is:**

[image]

I have searched Stackoverflow and the web without any results, or I am simply very bad at searching.

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457406/can-i-apply-multiple-background-colors-with-css3

Comment: Definitely use a gradient.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [linear-gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) to achieve this.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xpqhsv0z/)

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,
        #F6D6A8 20%,
        #F5BA55 20%, #F5BA55 40%,
        #F09741 40%, #F09741 60%,
        #327AB2 60%, #327AB2 80%,
        #3A94F6 80%);
}
```

Just add vendor prefixes for additional browser support

```
body {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #F6D6A8 20%, #F5BA55 20%, #F5BA55 40%, #F09741 40%, #F09741 60%, #327AB2 60%, #327AB2 80%, #3A94F6 80%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #F6D6A8 20%, #F5BA55 20%, #F5BA55 40%, #F09741 40%, #F09741 60%, #327AB2 60%, #327AB2 80%, #3A94F6 80%);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #F6D6A8 20%, #F5BA55 20%, #F5BA55 40%, #F09741 40%, #F09741 60%, #327AB2 60%, #327AB2 80%, #3A94F6 80%);
}
```

Browser support can be found [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients).

Comment: Good one , yours is much better than mine.Voted!

Comment: Seems to work well without `html, body { height: 100%; }` too. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3vxknbd/5/)

Comment: @webinista Yea, you're right, it will work in most circumstances, but look at what happens when you add `margin: 0` to the `body` element. [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/qb04zz1o/). Adding `html, body { height: 100%; }` will cover most use cases, [see](http://jsfiddle.net/56phkasu/)

Answer (score 5):

Look at this i made a trick for this .http://jsfiddle.net/753gugpt/

I used [linear-gradient](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) CSS3 property like this:

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  /*or 900px for example */
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#exampleB {
  width: 32700px;
  height: 285px;
  background-color: #a8e9ff;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1, startColorstr=#a8e9ff, endColorstr=#052afc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #a8e9ff 0%, #052afc 0%, #485e69 12%, #ff8d00 1%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(left, #a8e9ff 0%, #052afc 0%, #485e69 12%, #ff8d00 1%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #a8e9ff 0%, #052afc 0%, #485e69 12%, #ff8d00 1%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #a8e9ff 0%, #052afc 0%, #485e69 12%, #ff8d00 1%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #a8e9ff 0%, #052afc 0%, #485e69 12%, #ff8d00 1%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #a8e9ff), color-stop(0%, #052afc), color-stop(12%, #485e69), color-stop(1%, #ff8d00));
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="exampleB"></div>
</div>
```

Maybe this will work for you :)

Comment: As i said @Josh Crozier 's solution is much better than it was mine. But it still works in one way! :)  Thanks!