# manipulate color of browser window when scrolling beyond the top or bottom

Tags: html, css, colors

When I scroll using trackpad there is a white gap between toolbar and the main window(above THIS IS TOP heading). You can see it in the images I attached. This gap ONLY appears when I scroll beyond the top or bottom at the bottom of the window with trackpad(not mouse). How can I set the color of that background beyond the "normal" window?

[image]

// When I don't scroll:

[image]

```css
    @import url("960_12_col.css");
    
    #header{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .grid_4{
    /* 
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 20px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
     */
    
    }
    .grid_3{
    padding:10px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 140px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    #comment1{
    text-align: left;
    }
    #comment2{
    text-align: center;
    }
    #comment3{
    text-align: center;
    }
    #comment4{
    text-align: right;
    }
    
    #leftImage{
    }
    
    #centerImage{
    }
    #rightImage{
    }
    .image{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 20px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    }
    .text{
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #C6E2FF;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    }
    body{
    /* 
    background-image: url("images/kaktus2.jpg");
    background-repeat:repeat;
     */
     
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#66cccc), to(#336666));
    /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#336666, #66cccc); 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    /* background-color: red; */
    
    }
    
    #top{
    position:fixed;
    /* 
    margin:0px;
     */
    top:0px;
    left:80px;
    
    right:80px;
     */
    text-align: center;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: magenta;
    
    
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
    <!--   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/960_12_col_rtl.css"> -->
      <link href="css/custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
     <body>
     <div id="top" class="grid_12"> <h1>THIS IS TOP</h1></div>
     <div class="container_12 clearfix">
      <div id="header" class="grid_12">
       <h1>HUHUHUHU</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="comment1" class="grid_3">
         <p>This is comment 1!</p>
      </div>
      <div id="comment2" class="grid_3">
         <p>This is comment 2!</p>
      </div>
      <div id="comment3" class="grid_3">
         <p>This is comment 3!</p>
      </div>
      <div id="comment4" class="grid_3">
         <p>This is comment 4!</p>
      </div>
     
        <div class="grid_4 image" >
         <p id="image1">image1</p>
        </div>    
        <div class="grid_4 image">
         <p id="image2">image2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_4 image">
         <p id="image3">image3</p>
        </div>
        
        
        <div id="underLeftImage" class="grid_4 text">
         <p id="underLeftImageText">image3</p>
        </div>
            
        <div id="underCenterImage" class="grid_4 text">
         <p id="underCenterImageText">image3</p>
        </div>    
        <div id="underRightImage" class="grid_4 text">
         <p id="underRightImageText">image3</p>
        </div>
     </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Umm.. can you show us how you have done this? Some code so that we can find out where to help you?

Comment: sure, I added it to the question. I am new to htmland css. Do web designers use an online tool to share code? It would be cleaner to attach a link with code..

Comment: Yes. see https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my tests (messing around with the CSS inspector in Chrome on this SO page), it's based on the `background-color` of the `body` element.

So for a green bar at the top of the page, you'd do this:

```
body {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Note that it doesn't inherit a background image, so if you want the illusion of the background gradient continuing then you'd need to find the color of the topmost pixel of your background image and use that.

Comment: aa I see. That helped a lot! Finding the rgb of the topmost pixel is an easy task. Is it possible to specify the top background-color to be darkgreen and the bottom one to be light green? That would create seamless transiiton. if i specify just one color, lets say darkgreen, than at the bottom of the page I get a crude transition.

Comment: Using just `background-color`? Nope. It only takes a single value. You *may* have some luck with using an absolutely-positioned `:before` element (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457406/can-i-apply-multiple-background-colors-with-css3) but I have a feeling the pseudo-element will scroll with the rest of the document when you reach the top/bottom of the screen, meaning that solution won't work. You may need to pick which part of the screen is most important to have the correct background color for, and run with a single value...