# Multiple background colors, images in css

Tags: html, css

How can I give a single `div` multiple background colors or images in CSS? For example, I want the top part to be red, then the middle to be blue and the bottom to be green.

Comment: Hi, take a look at this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6457484/4362192

Answer (score 6):

A single `linear-gradient` as a background is enough

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
    red 0, red 33.33%, 
    blue 0, blue 66.66%, 
    green 0, green 100%
);
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGXmON) | [Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients)

Comment: Nice. Can you explain what the 0's without % signs do?

Comment: it's how color-stop work: when you set a color stop whose value is lower than the previous color stops it automatically sets to the largest value defined before. So it is equivalent to write `red 0, red 33.33%,  blue 33.33, blue 66.66%, green 66.66, green 100%` but there are less repeated values (e.g. if you changed 66.66 with 80% you should change the value twice)

Answer (score 2):

**use gradients in css3.**

```
YourDIVID {
  background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow, green); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(red, yellow, green); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow, green); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow, green); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**TOP, BOTTOM, CENTER multiple color Tutorial For Sigle Line**

```
#multiple {
width: 700px;
height: 500px;
background:linear-gradient(red, yellow, green, blue, purple, orange);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Use [`:before` and `:after` pseudo element rules](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) to have three different background layers (color and images) on a single element**.

**Note:** This solution requires the contained elements to be wrapped to stay above the backgrounds. Otherwise links may not be clickable, text not selectable, etc..

Run the code snippet for a working example.

```css
.layered-backgrounds {
  background-color: #C63;
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.layered-backgrounds:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  top: 0;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #39C;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.layered-backgrounds:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  bottom: 0;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #9C3;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.layered-backgrounds .content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="layered-backgrounds">
    <div class="content">
        <a href="#">Clickable</a> and selectable contents.
    </div>
</div>
```