# How to place a half filled background for a div

Tags: html, css

I saw this UI design and its really beautiful. I would love to use this design in my web app.

[image]

I have a fixed header and a fixed footer. In the middle, there are the main content, with 95% of screen width.

demo: [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/karlars/pen/xOOMLG?editors=1100)

```
<header>
  <div id="header_wrapper">
    <nav>
      <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"> </i> </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<div id="main_content">
  <div id="profile_wrapper">
    <div id="profile_image" style="background-image:url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/765-default-avatar.png)"></div>
    <div id="profile_username">Usernamae</div>
  </div>
  <div id="some_content">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae suscipit quaerat dolore assumenda voluptate. Molestias accusamus fugiat quam illo impedit aliquid eligendi assumenda molestiae, quis, ratione, fugit dicta dolore praesentium.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I don't get is, how can I have a background which will have 50% height of the profile-image for that profile-image div, and have 100% width of the screen, since my main-content has 95% of screen width?

Comment: This is Google Material  design  lite, you can use it from their CSS and JS

Comment: Your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457406/can-i-apply-multiple-background-colors-with-css3. Your background needs to be `linear-gradient(lightblue 50%, white 50%)`

Comment: @Harry I believe this is different. The question there yields _a_ possible way to achieve the effect, but this is asking specifically about a different method. This is about having the background half-filled, rather than cutting out a part of the background.

Comment: @AndrewMyers: That is why I added the clause within my comment. The last line says *What I don't get is, how the background of the profile image is half filled, if you know what I mean.* which to me is not talking about the half filled background but the image with a transparent cut. There are different ways of interpreting though and that's why I hadn't hammered it.

Comment: Not a problem @Karl. If this information had been provided earlier, it would've avoided all confusions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method (by no means the only one) would be to add an `::after` pseudo-element on the parent, which adds another background. For example:

```
#profile_wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#profile_wrapper:after {
  content: "";

  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  right: 0;

  background: white;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

That pseudo-element will apply a white color to the lower half of the parent. Note that the other children, such as the profile image itself, must be given a positive `z-index` to stay on top.

For what it's worth, pseudo-elements have [*slightly*](http://caniuse.com/#search=pseudo-elements) [wider](http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20backgrounds) support than multiple background images, as long as you use single-colon syntax (`:after`). Basically, it's just IE8. And if you're having to worry about IE8...

[Here is a version of this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNNgKa) applied to your pen.

Comment: Yes. This is what I was looking for. There's just some slight problem. Since, the `main_content` div has a width of 720px, the "half-filled background" itself also has 720px. Can it have 100% width of the screen? Also, while scrolling up, the `profile-image` div is at the top of the `header`. Is there any way this can be corrected, so that `header` will always be at the top? Thank you.

Comment: If you want the blue color to be full width, you have to make the `#profile_wrapper` full width. You could put in another wrapper element to keep the rest of the profile content in place. As for the `<header>`... That's the magic of `z-index`. When you start having to `z-index` one thing, you have to `z-index` a lot of other things. But that sort of header is usually `z-index`ed anyway.